# Amana Prestige Air Con fan won't spin

Tags: hvac, repair, air-conditioning, fans, central-air

I have an old Amana Air Con unit that stopped working. The fan won't spin. The condenser kicks in. I can manually spin the fan and it goes like a champ. I have replaced the cap already. Any ideas or maybe a bad replacement cap?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A problem like this probably needs on-site diagnosis, but more info (model? pictures?) might help.

Comment: It is probably time to replace the fan motor.

Comment: It is an Amana Prestige. RCB24B2D is the model. I got a MARS - Motors & Armatures 11966 Motor Start Capacitor with 145-175 uf MFD as the recommended replacement. [Photo1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17L43qckYS9tRCqpVyruH7QsH9Vudruhr/view?usp=sharing)                       [Photo2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QHUfg__OM-73DzwhLBSYB8AvTt1k27DB)  [Photo3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10hRqJKArKxvMEuJB7h275f9Gzh3nErOW) [Photo4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11L02rSB43qIwuWwxODspHmxDRQuBJsrg) [Photo5](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cc9lxMn5VaLUP1w-evRWgOKIKUnUYURd)